# VBA Left function issues

Tags: excel, vba

I,m trying to use left function like in this basic example code and it gives me compile error,However it works when I use Right function instead of Left can figure out why.

Example code:

```
Public Sub LeftSub()
Dim SourceRange As Range, DestinationRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set SourceRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10")  
Set DestinationRange = Workbooks("xx.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

For i = 1 To SourceRange.Count
DestinationRange(i, 1).Value = Left(SourceRange(i, 1).Value, 2)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please try `DestinationRange(i, 1).Value = VBA.Strings.Left(SourceRange(i, 1).Value, 2)`? If that works, then someone has overwritten `Left` with another function using the same name "Left". This is bad style.

Comment: Are you sure you did non define a user function or variable with name Left? You can check this by right-clicking on `Left` and selection `Definition` in the menu.

Comment: I figured it out already another module using left functions somehow caused this deleted it and it works ,but thank you :)

Comment: You should also add a check to ensure that `SourceRange(i, 1).Value` has a length of at least 2, because `Left` will error if you use a position longer than the string itself

Comment: That's what I did but I didn't involved it in to this example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Left` could resolve to (in that order):

1. A local variable named `Left`
2. A module-scoped variable, or a member in the same module
3. A member in the base class (e.g. `UserForm.Left` in a form module)
4. A public/global member in a standard module of the same project
5. A public/global member in the VBA standard library or any referenced project (in the order specified in the *project references* dialog)

The first match is the one that is used, *regardless of its signature*:

[image: IntelliSense showing how Left resolves to a same-module Left function even with a completely different signature]

This function's identifier is *hiding* the built-in one. To access the built-in `Left` function, you need to qualify it now:

```
Debug.Print VBA.Strings.Left(...)
```

Slightly unrelated, but notice `VBA.Strings.Left` returns an implicit `Variant`:

[image]

And its little strongly-typed little brother returns an explicit `String`:

[image]

And therefore avoids the cost of implicit type conversions; prefer `Left$` to `Left` whenever the `String` parameter can never be `Null` - the two functions are very similar, except for this:

```
Debug.Print Left(Null, 1)  ' outputs Null
Debug.Print Left$(Null, 1) ' raises runtime error 94 - Invalid use of Null
```

That said unless you're dealing with [access-vba](/questions/tagged/access-vba), you'll probably never encounter a `Null` in VBA.

Comment: Note that `Left("abc", 2)` works on a `UserForm` even though there is `UserForm.Left` property already defined. If you define `Right` custom property on a `UserForm` then `Right("abc", 2)` stops working in form scope. . . `Left` is tough!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me w/o compile error:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LeftSub()
    Dim SourceRange As Range, DestinationRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set SourceRange = Range("B1:B10")
    Set DestinationRange = Range("A1:A10")

    For i = 1 To SourceRange.Count
        DestinationRange(i, 1).Value = Left(SourceRange(i, 1).Value, 2)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: didn't work for me :( but thanks **figured it out already another module using left function was causing troubles